# Is there a jQuery plugin that does a slideout on hover for text?

Tags: jquery

So i have this structure html

```
<span class="label" data="data/support_icon.png">
<span class="title">1 User/Location - 8Am - 8Pm Mon - Fri Support Plan - Level 1</span>
<small class="rt">0.0000</small>
</span>
```

and the problem is the text is too long so what i want is maybe truncate at n number of characters and when you hover over it you will get the rest of the text....I was wondering if there is a jQuery plugin that willdo this or an easy way to implement this

Comment: You can put your long text in title and put short text in html so on mouse hover it will show as tooltip <span class="title" title="1 User/Location - 8Am - 8Pm Mon - Fri Support Plan - Level 1">1 User/Location...</span>

Comment: @Birey Instead of truncating the text you can fix the width and just specify the overflow to [elipses](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/CSS/Text-overflow) as well.

Comment: any suggestions on a good tooltip plugin for this??

Comment: @Andrew DO you have an example on how to do that

Comment: @Andrew Thanks for the tip. Its nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work in all recent browsers,

```
<style>
.title{
  width: 200px; 
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  -ms-text-overflow: ellipses;
  -o-text-overflow: ellipses;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
</style>
<span class="label" data="data/support_icon.png">
<div class="title" title="1 User/Location - 8Am - 8Pm Mon - Fri Support Plan - Level 1">1 User/Location - 8Am - 8Pm Mon - Fri Support Plan - Level 1</div>
<small class="rt">0.0000</small>
</span>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/EXjmn/